# Solving $y''+4y = (x+1) e^{-2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation. 
I found $ ± 2i $ as homogeneous solutions and then i suppose as particolar solution

$$ y = (ax+b)e^{-2x} $$

So i find

$$\begin{align}
y' &= ae^{-2x}-2(ax+b)e^{-2x} \\
y'' &= e^{-2x}(-a+4ax+4b) 
\end{align}$$

and then I substitute

$$ 8ax +8b - a = x+1 $$

$$\begin{cases}
8a = 1 \\ 
8b - a = 1
\end{cases}
$$

and so I find $ a = 1/8 $ and $ b = 9/16$. The general solution became

$$ y = c_1 \cos(2x) + c_2 \sin(2x) + (\frac x8 + \frac{9}{16}) e^{-2x} $$

but I see that the solution should be

$$ y = e^{-2x}(\frac{x^3-3x^2}{6}+c_1x+c_2) $$

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with $y''$. Indeed, it should be

$$y''(x) = -4a e^{-2x} + 4b e^{-2x} + 4axe^{-2x}$$

Check it.

Comment: You are right, but I still don't find the correct solution

Comment: The provided solution can not be correct, the homogeneous term should be $c_1\cos(2x)+c_2\sin(2x)$.

Comment: Check the homogeneous solution, which is wrong too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative seems dubious, it should be
$$
y''=-2ae^{−2x}-2(a−2ax-2b)e^{−2x}=(-4a+4ax+4b)e^{−2x}
$$
so that
$$
y''+4y=(-4a+8ax+8b)e^{−2x}=(x+1)e^{−2x}
$$
which should give $a=1/8$ and $b=3/16$, everything else as in the solution you found. That the provided solution has a totally different homogeneous part tells you that it is a solution to a different problem.

Comment: Thanks, I checked on wolfram alpha and this is the correct solution, the one reported on the book is wrong

Comment: You would find a solution of the reported type if not exactly that if the left side of the equation were $y''+4y'+4y$.